# Deserializing result from Web Service call to a child element type

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I've connected to a web service and downloading XML which I'm trying to deserialize. However, the XML has  a top level element of a different type than the child element that I'm trying to serialize to.

```
<ServiceResponse xmlns="namespace1">
  <ServiceResult xmlns:i="namespace2">
   ...lots of elements
  </ServiceResult>
</ServiceResponse>
```

I've written the following code:

```
public MyData ConvertXmlToMyData(string filepath)
{
     XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
     xRoot.ElementName = "ServiceResponse";
     xRoot.Namespace = @"namespace1";
     xRoot.IsNullable = true;

     XmlSerializer reader = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyData), xRoot);
     StreamReader file = new StreamReader(filepath);

     MyData result = (MyData)reader.Deserialize(file);
     file.Close();
     return result;
}
```

The code executes with no exception, but all the underlying elements are null.  I know this is because `ServiceResponse` is not the same as `ServiceResult`, but I don't know how to specify that I want the deserialization to happen on the child element, not the whole object (there are no other elements, just a single child of type `ServiceResult`).

The only solutions I've seen state that I should edit the declaration of the types, but in my situation I'm getting them from a web service so I can't do that.

Does anyone know what I should be doing instead?

Edit: added details of the MyData annotations from the service reference

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="MyData", Namespace="namespace2")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public partial class MyData: object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {
```

Edit 2:

Changed code to:

```cs
public MyData ConvertXmlToMyData(string filepath)
{
    DataContractSerializer reader = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyData));

    StreamReader file = new StreamReader(filepath);

    file.BaseStream.Position = 0;

    MyData result = (MyData)reader.ReadObject(file.BaseStream); <- error thrown here

    file.Close();

    return result;
}
```

Now seeing error:

> Error in line 1 position 73. Expecting element 'MyData' from namespace 'namespace1'..
> Encountered 'Element'  with name 'ServiceResponse', namespace 'namespace1'.

Comment: It is unclear (at least for me) what exactly you are looking for. Do you want to deserialize the `ServiceResult` node only?

Comment: Please also share with us how does the `MyData` class is declared and xml annotated.

Comment: @PeterCsala Yes that's right, I just need the ServiceResult part. The MyData class is provided by the service reference, it is not declared by me.

Comment: The annotations are quite important here. Does the `ServiceResponse` have a `XmlRootAttribute` on it? Does the `ServiceResult` property of the `ServiceResponse` have a `XmlElementAttribute`? Without the mapping we can't help you.

Comment: @PeterCsalaThanks for your input, but I don't really understand what you're asking.  I've added info for the MyData definition from the service reference into the original question above.  ServiceResult & ServiceResponse are the XML tags.  Everything I know about them is in the XML posted in the question. I can tell by the members that ServiceResult is the same data type as MyData and that's why I'm trying to deserialize it to that type.  Hope that helps.

Comment: `XmlSerializer` serializes/deserializes only public fields/properties. It has nothing to do with `SerializableAttribute`. The serialization and deseralization process can be controlled via the `XmlElementAttribute`, `XmlAttributeAttribute`, ...

Comment: On the other hand as I can see you can take advantage of the `DataContractAttribute`. You can do that by using the `DataContractSerializer` class instead of the `XmlSerializer`. [Sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/datacontractserializer-sample)

Comment: Did it solve your problem by changing the serializer to `DataContractSerializer` ?

Comment: @PeterCsala I'm now getting a different error, I've put the new code & exception details into the post above.  Thanks

Comment: The error indicates 2 things: 1) You try to convert the top-level entity as a second-level entity. 2) The `DataContractAttribute` specifies a bad `Name`: `MyData` instead of  `ServiceResult`. You have to fix the `Name` attribute and provide the top level entity to the `DataContractSerializer`.

Comment: The data type provided by the service is 'MyData'.  Within the XML, it's called 'Service Result'.  I don't know why they are different, but that's out of my control.  I want the second-level entity as type 'MyData', and AFAIK there is no data type for the top-level entity exposed by the service, otherwise I'd have just converted to that type then extracted the child element.  I'm not sure how to move forwards, do you have any advice?

Comment: I've left an answer with a working example. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Sorry for the delay @PeterCsala, I've been sick with covid.  I will try later today and let you know.  Thanks again for your help

Comment: Your health should be the number 1 priority. Everything else can wait.

Comment: topLevelEntity returns null

Comment: Here is the working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y461G5 Please copy-paste the code into a console app, because dotnet fiddle does not like `DataContractSerializer` for whatever reason.

Comment: I think we're nearly there, but this line is throwing the following: var myData = (MyData)deserializer.ReadObject(resultReader);
  Message=Expecting element 'MyData' from namespace 'namespace1'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'ServiceResult', namespace 'namespace1'.

Note: I've not been able to add the DataContract to the data type because that type is provided by the service reference, I do not declare it myself

Comment: Because the mapping between your domain object and the serialized data is defined via the `DataContractAttribute` that's why you need to fix the `Name` property of it. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: I just opened the definition from the service reference and it says [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="MyData", Namespace="namespace1")]

Comment: ok, changing the name property on the DataContractAttribute works; I guess this is a design flaw in how the service reference has been created.  But it's working so I am very grateful :)  Thank you

Comment: I'm glad that it worked for you. If you have find my guidance useful please accept my proposal as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose your xml file looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ServiceResponse xmlns="namespace1">
  <ServiceResult xmlns:i="namespace2">
    <desc>1</desc>
  </ServiceResult>
</ServiceResponse>
```

I've just added an `xml` and a `desc` to your sample.

Then in order to skip the top-level entity we need to semi-parse the xml. One way to do this:

1. `Load` the `FileStream` into an `XDocument`
2. Find the top-level entity
3. Find the second-level entity

```cs
//Step #1
var xml = File.OpenRead("sample.xml");
var semiParsedData = XDocument.Load(xml);

//Step #2
const string topNamespace = "namespace1", firstNode = "ServiceResponse";
const StringComparison comparison = StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;

var topLevelEntity = semiParsedData.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(element => 
        string.Equals(element.Name.Namespace.NamespaceName, topNamespace, comparison)
        && string.Equals(element.Name.LocalName, firstNode, comparison));

//Step #3
const string secondNode = "ServiceResult";
var secondLevelEntity = topLevelEntity?.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(element =>
    string.Equals(element.Name.Namespace.NamespaceName, topNamespace, comparison)
    && string.Equals(element.Name.LocalName, secondNode, comparison));

if (secondLevelEntity == null)
    return;
```

Hopefully there is a method called `CreateReader`, which is defined on the `XNode` class.

- The `secondLevelEntity` is a `XElement` instance.
- `XElement` is  inherited from `XContainer`.
- `XContainer` is inherited from `XNode`.

So, we can call the `CreateReader` on the `secondLevelEntity`:

```cs
using var resultReader = secondLevelEntity.CreateReader();
```

The `resultReader` is a `XmlReader` instance and hopefully the `DataContractSerializer`'s `ReadObject` has an overload which accepts a `XmlReader`:

```cs
var deserializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyData));
var myData = (MyData)deserializer.ReadObject(resultReader);
Console.WriteLine(myData.Description);
```

And finally the data model should look like this:

```cs
[DataContract(Name = "ServiceResult", Namespace = "namespace1")]
public class MyData
{
    [DataMember(Name = "desc")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```